# 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in the database called `DB_Interface` like this:

```
USE [DB_Interface]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcToCCreate]
```

It throws error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.
>
> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.`

This is my first stored procedure - not sure if I cannot use `Create` or `Alter` like I used it. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: In `ORACLE` it's possible not in `MSSQL`. For `MSSQL` you have to use either `CREATE PROCEDURE [spname] or ALTER PROCEDURE [spname]`

Comment: Either `CREATE` or `ALTER` keyword is used not both

Comment: I tried to give directly ALTER Procedure earlier but it was saying Invalid object name.I even did Refresh local Cache.  So tried giving Create or Alter. What could be the issue

Comment: `ALTER PROCEDURE [spname]` will only work if your stored procedure exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcToCCreate]
```

OR

```
CREATE  PROC [dbo].[ProcToCCreate]
```

are only valid syntax in SQL Server.

If you want to `ALTER` procedure, here is the syntax

```
 ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcToCCreate]
```

Comment: Or can I directly use ALTER PROCEDURE?

Comment: @trx : Yeah, you can. Updated my answer.

Comment: I tried to give directly ALTER Procedure earlier but it was saying Invalid object name.I even did Refresh local Cache. So tried giving Create or Alter. What could be the issue

Comment: @trx : are you sure your proc exists in DB `DB_Interface`?

Answer (score 8):

```
CREATE OR ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcToCCreate]
AS
RETURN;
```

is allowed Syntax in (probably) SQL-Server 2016 (only tested on SQL-Server 2016 with SP1)

Answer (score 2):

**CREATE:**

```
USE [DB_Interface]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcToCCreate]

AS

RETURN
```

**ALTER:**

```
    USE [DB_Interface]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcToCCreate]

    AS

    RETURN
```